How to send silent push notifications to Android using Baidu and Azure Notification hubs?
I am using the baidu android SDK to receive push notifications on Android devices. Everything works, except every notification enters this method
public void onNotificationArrived(Context context, String title, String description, String customContentString)
instead of
public void onMessage(Context context, String message, String customContentString, int i, int i1), which is for silenced push notifications.
Is there a parameter that needs to be added to the payload of the notification for it to be silent?
I tried adding msg_type:0 and msgType:0 to the payload as described in the baidu faq page, but not even those worked.
